# notification works on emulator, but not on real device

Tags: android

I use the following code to send notification sound to user. This works perfect on the emulator, but not on a real device. Real device just remains silent.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getReactApplicationContext())
        .setContentTitle("foo")
    .setContentText("bar")
        .setSound(soundUri, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
        .setAutoCancel(true);

notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Here are the app permissions I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_SERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_MIDI_DEVICE_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_USE_DATA_IN_BACKGROUND" />
```

Emulator target is Androd 6.0 on API v 23

What else could it be? Thanks

Comment: Mention the API level of emulator and device in question .

Comment: Did you try when app is closed?? try it once you have to handle push notification manually when app is open

Comment: Application was open.
Emulator target is Androd 6.0 on API v 23

Comment: Sometime what happens is that, there are some battery optimization services are running on the real devices, which block the notifications. Go to your battery settings, and whitelist your app.

Comment: That was it - the phone was in a battery save mode. That was blocking notifications. I'd never thought about that. Thanks. If you'd like to put it as answer, I will accept it